# Trying to get two vbox next to each other

Tags: extjs, vbox

I have two `vbox` that I want right next to each other.  However, only the first one is showing up.  Why is this and how do I change it?  Here is my code

```
  layout: 'fit',
  title: 'Avail Requests Details',
  minWidth: 1000,
  minHeight: 600,
  width: 1174,
  height: 600,
  autoShow: true,
  //listeners: {
  //    beforedestroy: 'onBeforeDestroy'
  //},

  items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    reference: 'viewForm',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaults: {
      xtype: 'container',
      height: 25,
      layout: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      defaults: {
        columnWidth: 0.3,
        labelWidth: 140
      }
    },
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'CHANNEL',
      name: 'Channel'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'ADVERTISER',
      name: 'AdvertiserName'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'DEMO',
      name: 'Demo'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'COMMENTS',
      name: 'comments'
    }],
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'CHANNEL',
      name: 'Channel'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'ADVERTISER',
      name: 'AdvertiserName'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'DEMO',
      name: 'Demo'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      fieldLabel: 'COMMENTS',
      name: 'comments'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Suggest you read the docs for `layout: 'fit'`. You want `hbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `items` definition in your `form`, so second just overrite first, not adding new one. Also you have to use `hbox` layour for parent component.

I updated your code, check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14ml).